# What is the best way to render a template inside a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I would like to generate a PDF from a model, using the Prawn gem. Below is my solution, but it calls `ActionController::Base.new()` from inside the model.

Currently, the below code works. Is there a suggestion for a better way to accomplish this?

```
class Certificate < ApplicationRecord

  has_one_attached :pdf

  def self.generate_for(student)
    @user = student

    certificate = student.build_certificate()

    action_controller = ActionController::Base.new()  

    template_string = action_controller.render_to_string template: 'certificates/certificate'

    io = StringIO.new template_string

    certificate.pdf.attach(
      io: io,
      filename: "filename",
      content_type: 'application/pdf',
      identify: false
    )

    certificate.save
  end

end
```

Comment: Could you share  more detail on what do yo mean when you say 'save' a pdf? do you want to create upload this pdf somewhere when an endpoint is hit, and associate it with the user? or maybe create on the fly and download  this pdf from a link?

Comment: Yes, when an event is triggered in the rails app, I want to run some generation code that creates a PDF and saves it to S3, using Active Storage. The PDF will be designed using the Prawn DSL. Typically this is done in a Rails view, so I'm not sure how to generate the DSL template from the model.

Comment: By convention, model should be used to deal with database operations only but it doesn't stop you to write business logic in model just like what you did. The better way is to extract the business logic in separate class and service object is very popular design pattern community uses. Take a look at https://thoughtbot.com/blog/skinny-controllers-skinny-models